# How can I load a Zend Framework plugin?

Tags: zend-framework

I have created a plugins directory in the application directory.

Currently I am loading the plugins like so:

```
protected function _initAccessCheck()
{ 
    include('../application/plugins/AccessCheck.php');
    $fc = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $fc->registerPlugin( new Plugin_AccessCheck() );
}
```

What would I have to do so I would not have to use the include function?  Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource` allows you to define a mapping between file paths and class names. This allows you to autoload classes whose files are not stored on the include path.

Typically, you would use the subclass `Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader` which sets up some common mappings for models, forms, etc. In particular, it has an entry for plugins. In Bootstrap, it would be something like this:

```
protected function _initResourceLoader()
{
    $resourceLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => 'Application',
        'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH,
    ));
    return $resourceLoader;
}
```

Then a class named `Application_Plugin_MyPlugin` would reside in the file `application/plugins/MyPlugin.php`.

In your specific circumstance, it looks like you are using an empty namespace. So your's would be:

```
protected function _initResourceLoader()
{
    $resourceLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => '',
        'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH,
    ));

    return $resourceLoader;
}
```

Then your plugin class `Plugin_AccessCheck` would reside in the file `application/plugins/AccessCheck.php`.

Just make sure that the resource loader is created *before* you instantiate/register your plugins:

```
protected function _initAccessCheck()
{ 
    $this->booststrap('resourceLoader');
    $fc = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $fc->registerPlugin( new Plugin_AccessCheck() );
}
```

Comment: Thank you @David Weinraub for your response.  It worked. Can this be done through application.ini ?  Does Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader load all the PHP files in the specified directory or does it simply add the directory to the include path? What if I were using a namespace? What difference would that make?

Comment: You can register the plugin using `application.ini` with something like: `resources.frontController.plugins.accesscheck = "Application_Controller_Plugin_AccessCheck"`. But it only works for plugins without constructor params. Otherwise, you need instantiate/register via code. It will only register plugins that you explicitly designate, _not_ all plugins in the folder. The namespace value given to the resource autoloader - `'Application'`, in this case - is part of the mapping between class names to load and places to look for them.

Answer (score 3):

I use application.ini file to enable plugins, in the following way:

For example, for an authentication control plugin I have the following:

```
class Application_Plugin_AuthCheck extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        //check if user is logged in
    }    
}
```

And then I add it at application.ini

```
resources.frontController.plugins.authcheck = Application_Plugin_AuthCheck
```

And it's now registered at application.

Note: I use dispatchLoopStartup but you could use another function as specified here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html